# Supabase Web App DB Design

Tags: database-design, postgres

I have the following Supabase db structure for my web app

Project -> Stage -> Logbook

- A project can have many stages (stage has a foreign key for project)
- A stage can have many logs (logs have foreign keys for stage).

Now, in the UI I need to be able to show logs in terms of a selected stage or selected project – I'm limiting it so you can only have either/or selected at a single moment, not both. However, using the straightforward queries for both (logs-for-stage(s) and logs for project) I get a nested result set – ideally I’d like just the logs and not the joint tables but I’m not sure how to express this from SQL.

Further, in order to be able to query and receive just logs, I instead thought about adding a `project_id` column to the `logbook` table. This way I would not have to join through `projects` and `stages` in order to get the logs for a particular project – I just select those logs with that project id. But, is this bad in any sense? Is it going against the relationships I’ve expressed?